# how to show uploaded image storing it in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have made an object in which I am storing user's name, age , email and an image uploaded by him.
I want to show his uploaded image in a div(say), I am not getting how to do this thing. I have tried this:

```
$(function () {
    $('img').load(function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        // Copy the image contents to the canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        localStorage[this.id] = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    })
})
```

but how to display this image using javascript or jquery? (without any plugin)
I have 5 such objects to be displayed on the page. 
Any solution will help. Thanks

Comment: please format your post with code blocks.  it's not very easy to read.

Comment: Someone else already fixed your formatting. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to learn how to format code properly.

Comment: how is this related to backbone.js?

Comment: I want to store an image in local storage and then retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

**try this, it works fine**

```
 <input type="file" id="image-input" />
        <img id="image-container" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
              /** @type {Node} */
          var imgInput = document.getElementById( "image-input" ),
              /** @type {Node} */
              imgContainer = document.getElementById( "image-container" ),
              /** Restore image src from local storage */
              updateUi = function() {
                imgContainer.src = window.localStorage.getItem( "image-base64" );
              },
              /** Register event listeners */
              bindUi = function(){
                imgInput.addEventListener( "change", function(){
                  if ( this.files.length ) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function( e ){
                      window.localStorage.setItem( "image-base64", e.target.result );
                      updateUi();
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL( this.files[ 0 ] );
                  }
                }, false );
              };

        updateUi();
        bindUi();
        }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture
    imgCanvas.width = this.width;
    imgCanvas.height = this.height;

    // Draw image into canvas element
    imgContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imgCanvas.width,imgCanvas.height);
    // Save image as a data URL
    imgInfom = imgCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    localStorage.setItem("imgInfo",imgInfom);


    document.body.style.background = 'url('+imgInfom+')';
```

Here i am showing image as background image for body you can use other options also.